# MySQL "filegroup"?

Tags: mysql, filesystems

Coming for using Sql Server where there are file-groups, i was wondering if there is (i'm sure there is) something similar in MySQL. After all the database cant be limited to just one hard drive( if using windows that is). I've tried to search but its hard to find the something that you don't know the name of!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a MySQL Server instance stores all data files under a single *data directory*.

There are ways to use [symbolic links](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/symbolic-links.html) to spread files over multiple drives if you're clever.

Or you can use [Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) to store your database over multiple directories.  But I personally think the implementation of Partitioning prior to MySQL 5.5 is too awkward to be useful.

---

Re your comment about using a SAN:  Here's an article: [When would you use a SAN with MySQL?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/09/when-would-you-use-san-with-mysql/)

Comment: so ... i guess mysql should connect to a SAN?